# Emacs: Could one buffer have more than one major mode?

Tags: emacs

I am wondering if one Emacs buffer could have more than one major-mode applying on it.

For example, one buffer could have `web-mode` and `php-mode` at the same time.

I find many people are using this combination, but just wondering if it is mentioned in the Emacs manual.

Comment: `auto-complete-mode` is a **minor-mode** -- see line 1808 of `auto-complete.el`:  https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/auto-complete.el  Multiple *minor-modes* may (and generally do) exist while there is a `major-mode` such as `php-mode`.  For an example of a `major-mode` such as `php-mode`, see line 979 of `php-mode.el`:  https://github.com/ejmr/php-mode/blob/master/php-mode.el

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on the misunderstanding that `auto-complete-mode` is a major mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you are looking for [mumamo](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo), Multiple major modes.

Comment: Up-voted, but you should really be linking to http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes -- MuMaMo is but one of many libraries which have been written to work around this limitation. If you think MuMaMo is the one true way, it might be good to indicate why.